# GIT marks whole functions as modified after Eclipse file reformat

Tags: git

I've reformatted some Java files in an Android project and now GIT marks entire functions as modified. Since there are no changes outside the whitespace (just tabs, line breaks), is there a way to tell GIT to ignore that or to process it per line instead of the full function? I've looked at the settings, searched on the web, and read a bit in the documentation but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git diff -w

The -w ignores whitespace when comparing lines.

Comment: Any way to add this to "Git Gui" by Shawn Pearce ?

Comment: I've updated msysgit to the latest beta version and they have put an option to add custom cmd parameters to diff. It looks ok to me so far.